# multline problem

Tags: formatting

I have used multiline to break a equation but in the 2nd line it goes to the end. Can't we move the 2nd line more ahead?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{thesis}
\usepackage{amsmath}\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[left=1.25in, right=1.0in, top=1.25in, bottom=1.0in]{geometry}

\newcommand{\piRsquare}{\pi r^2}        

\title{{Study x}}       
\date{August 24, 2013}              
%
\begin{document} \baselineskip=22pt
        \begin{multline}
    \mathcal{A}(\phi + h) - \mathcal{A}(\phi) = c_d \int_0^T \left\{\int_0^\infty \left(-\ddot{\phi} + \frac{1}{r^{d-1}}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r^{d-1} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r}\right) - 2m^2\phi\right)hr^{d-1}dr\right\}dt \\
    + \mbox{ Boundary Terms } + O\left(\|h^2\|\right),
    \end{multline}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. For instance, what is your class? For `article` the first line is too wide. — You can add horizontal space at the end of the second (last) line with `\hspace*{<length>}`. Though, in your case, I’d simply add another ``\\`` after the `=`.

Comment: Lines in `multline` cannot be broken across a `\left`...`\right` group. And what do you mean by "ahead"? Left or right? Perhaps add some visual aid that shows exactly what you're after.

Comment: I meant to write the 2nd line in the left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn’t use `multline` if you don’t want the last line to be flushright. Use `equation` + `split` instead.

Add `\raisetag{\normalbaselineskip}` after `\end{split}` to get the equation number on the same line as the last term.

### Code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{thesis}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[left=1.25in, right=1.0in, top=1.25in, bottom=1.0in]{geometry}
\newcommand*{\hpheq}{\hphantom{{}={}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
  \mathcal{A}(\phi + h) - \mathcal{A}(\phi) &
    = c_d \int_0^T
      \left\{ \int_0^\infty
        \left(-\ddot{\phi} + \frac{1}{r^{d-1}}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}
          \left(r^{d-1} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r}\right)
          - 2m^2\phi\right)
        hr^{d-1} dr
      \right\} dt \\
    & \hpheq + \mbox{ Boundary Terms } + O\left(\|h^2\|\right),
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The primary line of your equation extended past the right margin, so I broke it into three lines.  Perhaps this is closer to what you wanted.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{multline}
\mathcal{A}(\phi + h) - \mathcal{A}(\phi)\\
= c_d \int_0^T 
\left\{\int_0^\infty \left(-\ddot{\phi} + 
\frac{1}{r^{d-1}}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r^{d-1} 
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r}\right) - 
2m^2\phi\right)hr^{d-1}dr\right\}dt \\
\hfil+ \mbox{ Boundary Terms } + O\left(\|h^2\|\right)~~,\hfil\hfil\hfil
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't the `=` be on the second line? Also, the spacing around `Boundary Terms` is too big, right?

Comment: @Mico -- if the comma weren't there, then the whole last line would be shifted to the far right.  (i don't disagree about the odd positioning) and a single `\hfill` at the end of the line would be ignored by an `\unskip` in the environment definition -- needs something (like the comma) to "stop" it.  and i agree with @Svend that the `=` should be at the beginning of the second line.